# Is there a way to validate dynamic key names in a Joi schema?

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

Is there a way I can validate a value like this with `Joi` so that I can verify it is an object with zero or more keys (of any name) and that each have values of either a string, number or boolean?

```
{
  dynamicallyNamedKey1: 'some value',
  dynamicallyNamedKey2: 4
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You're going to want to use `Joi`'s [`object().pattern()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectpatternregex-schema) method. It's specifically for validating objects with unknown keys.

To match against one or more datatypes on a single key you'll need [`alternatives().try()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#alternatives) (or simply pass an array of `Joi` types).

So the rule to match your needs would be:

```
Joi.object().pattern(/^/, Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.string(), Joi.number(), Joi.boolean()))
```

Comment: Note that a simple array `[]` is a shortcut for `Joi.alternatives()`. So you can just do: `Joi.object().pattern(/^/, [Joi.string(), Joi.number()])`