# Joi : validate object of variable number of keys

Tags: json, node.js, joi, dynogels

I am trying to write a validation method for the following object ( associative array ):

```
{
  "10:00": {
    discount: 10,
    time: "10:00",
  },
  "11:00": {
    discount: 11,
    time: "11:00",
  },
  ...
  ....
}
```

Using Joi (https://github.com/hapijs/joi) What i got so far is this:

```
Joi.object().keys(
            {time:{
                discount: Joi.number(),
                time: Joi.string(),
            }}
        ),
```

which is obviously wrong and failing with : `ValidationError: child "discounts" fails because ["10:00" is not allowed, "11:00" is not allowed]`

can anyone suggest how to write validation for objects with variable number of keys ( associative array )

Answer (score 1):

sorted it out after reading through : [Is there a way to validate dynamic key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050870/is-there-a-way-to-validate-dynamic-key-names)

```
Joi.object().pattern(/^/, [
            Joi.object({
                discount: Joi.number(),
                time: Joi.string()
            })
        ])
```