# Joi object key type

Tags: node.js, schema, joi

I have object with dynamic string keys with string values,

```
{
  [string]: string
}
```

how can I do this?

```
Joi.object().keys({
  [Joi.string()]: Joi.string()
})
```

not working :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to validate dynamic key names in a Joi schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050870/is-there-a-way-to-validate-dynamic-key-names-in-a-joi-schema)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use [Joi.object().pattern()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectpatternpattern-schema). From the Joi docs, this lets you provide:

> A pattern that can be either a regular expression or a joi schema that
>   will be tested against the unknown key names.

```
const schema = Joi.object().pattern(
    Joi.string(), Joi.string()
)
```