# Does Joi have the concept of "not"?

Tags: node.js, joi

### The Question

I have an object that has been parsed from a JSON string. I want to confirm that its fields contain only primitive types (e.g. number, boolean, string). Specifically, I would like to confirm that all of the field values are *not* an `object`.

Does Joi have the concept of `not`?  Can I do this without listing every possible non-object type?

### The Attempt

I attempted to use [`any.disallow`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#anyinvalidvalues---aliases-disallow-not) which is almost what I need (and, I realized after posting my question, is listed as having the alias `not`).

```
import Joi from 'joi'

const schema = Joi.object().keys({ 
  myKey: Joi.any().not(Joi.object()),
})
```

However this seems to take values.  This means it doesn't compare against schemas, and will consider any value that isn't the literal value returned by `Joi.object()` as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43063568/12865378) which allows you to only accept primitives, but it's not the `not` you're looking for:

```js
const example = { 2: 'str', 3: 4, 4: true, 5: { 3: 2 } }

Joi.object()
   .pattern(/^/, [Joi.boolean(), Joi.string(), Joi.number()])
   .validate(example)
```

Basically, `/^/` is regex for accepting arbitrary keys and the array is syntatic sugar for [`Joi.alternatives`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#alternatives).

Edit: I managed a schema that fails whenever the key is an object

```js
Joi.object()
   .pattern(/^/, Joi.when(Joi.object(), { then: Joi.forbidden() }))
   .validate(example)
```

I almost got there with

```js
Joi.object()
   .pattern(/^/, Joi.not(Object()))
   .validate(example)
```

But it only works with empty object such as `{}`, which I suspect it has to do with `Joi.not` only accepting literals.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the answer, for now, might be no.

That said, it is possible to define [custom validation functions](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#anycustommethod-description) for logic that isn't baked into Joi.

Something like the following does work:

```
import Joi from 'joi'

const schema = Joi.object().keys({ 
  myKey: Joi.any().custom(
    (value, helpers) => {
      if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
        return helpers.error('any.invalid');
      }
      return value
    },
    'is not an object',
  ),
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a "not" option.

Here's another alternative combining [.when](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anywhencondition-options) and [.forbidden](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anywhencondition-options):

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({ 
  myKey: Joi.any(),
}).when(Joi.object({ myKey: Joi.object() }), {
    then: Joi.object({ myKey: Joi.forbidden() })
});
```